# Create .csv file with Apache POI doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create a file .csv with `apache-poi` but this file is empty. For this example I want to create only header about this file so I do:

```
public byte[]...(File save_file) {
Workbook workbook = null;
    Sheet sheet = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream=null;

    try {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        createHeader(0,sheet);

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(save_file);

        workbook.write(outputStream);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("ERROR", exception);

    } finally {

    }
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
      log.info("SOTTO BYTE "+byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

and after the method "create_header":

```
private static void createHeader(int rowPosition,Sheet sheet) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowPosition);

    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);

    cell.setCellValue("DATE");

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("EMAIL");

}
```

The problem is the file is empty. In the first method I need to return the byte[] that represents the csv file. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You are not setting the cell to row . `row.createCell(0).setCellValue("DATE");`

Comment: You definitly should close the workbook. Though I don't think thats gonna solve it

Comment: @manfromnowhere That part is done properly. first he creates a row, then the cell and sets the cell value. Thats all right

Comment: @XtremeBaumer May be you are correct . I never tried that way . To be honest by seeing con't figured it out the issue.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It's strange..If I set "workbook.close();" , eclipse show me the red line and it gie me "The method close() is undefined for the type Workbook" ?

Comment: what `Workbook` did you import? Is it `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` or something else?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer OP must be using `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: There is `CSVPrinter` from `apache.common`. It's much more lightweight than `apache.poi` and easy to use. Try [it](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer the import is just correct with your suggest but it doesn't resolve my problem...maybe can be the version?

Comment: @manfromnowhere I dont mean the implementation. I am talking about the variable itself. Postilla which version do you use?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer poi-3.5 FINAL

Comment: Can you try to use a newer version? like 4.0.0?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes...i'm tring!

Comment: If it is a csv file, you can directly use a Filewriter and there is no need to use Workbook.

Comment: I can't change the library because all project is old and it's not mine but I don't why my byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length is 0